# Deserialize JSON into C# class containing two Dictionary properties

Tags: c#, .net, json, xamarin

I'm developing an app in Xamarin and I have a very simple JSON file made of objects I would like to deserialize in one shot into the C# Class I have in my domain. (I am using the **Newtonsoft Json.NET** Framework)

Each JSON object has 3 properties: Title, Default and Custom. Title is a simple string, while Custom and Default are a list of pairs.

```
{  
  "messages": [  
    {  
      "Title": "...",  
      "Default": {  
        "lang1": "...",  
        "lang2": "..."  
      },  
      "Custom": {  
        "lang1": "",  
        "lang2": ""  
      }  
    },  
    {  
      "Title": "...",  
      "Default": {  
        "lang1": "...",  
        "lang2": "..."  
      },  
      "Custom": {  
        "lang1": "",  
        "lang2": ""  
      }  
    }  
  ]  
}
```

The C# class only contains those same three properties:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MessageItem
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof (JsonDictionaryAttribute))]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Default { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonDictionaryAttribute))]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Custom { get; set; }
}
```

Now, as you can see, I have already tried to specifically define the class the JsonConverter should use to deserialize the two Dictionary attributes. Problem is, when I try to deserialize the JToken containing a single "message" object I get a **System.InvalidCastException**.

I have tried to deserialize it both by invoking

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Domain.MessageItem>(messageToken.ToString());
```

and

```
messageToken.ToObject<Domain.MessageItem>();
```

and I'm obviously getting the same result.

By deserializing the single token, though, it works just fine, so I'm pretty sure what I'm doing wrong is something in the flag declarations I am using in the class.

I hope some of you can help me with this! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either deserialize to dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, List<MessageItem>> messageItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<MessageItem>>>(yourJson);
foreach(MessageItem item in messageItems["messages"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
}
```

OR you could write a wrapper class:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MessageItems
{
    [JsonProperty("messages")]
    public List<MessageItem> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize to that

```
MessageItems messageItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageItems>(yourJson);
foreach(MessageItem item in messageItems.Messages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
}
```

To get those examples to work I had to remove the [JsonConverter(typeof (JsonDictionaryAttribute))] attributes from your MessageItem class and replace with [JsonProperty].

Answer (score 1):

You have the proper class setup for a single `MessageItem`, but the JSON you posted is a `List<MessageItem>`.

Create the following class:

```
public class MessageList {
    [JsonProperty]
    public List<MessageItem> messages { get; set; }
}
```

and use `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageList>(messageToken.ToString())` and that should do the trick.